# CNN seems doing good during training and validation but not really

Tags: classification, tensorflow, cnn, binary

I'm doing a simple binary classification using this [dataset](https://data.mendeley.com/datasets/gjmr63rz2r/1)

```
import os


train_dir = "/tmp/Dataset/TrainingandValidation"
fire = os.path.join(train_dir, 'fire')
nofire = os.path.join(train_dir, 'nofire')

test_dir = "/tmp/Dataset/Testing/"
tfire = os.path.join(test_dir, 'fire')
tnofire = os.path.join(test_dir, 'nofire')


from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

test_data = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1.0/255.)
train_data = ImageDataGenerator (rescale= 1.0/255.)

train_images = train_data.flow_from_directory (train_dir,
                                               batch_size= 20,
                                               class_mode='binary',
                                               target_size=(150,150))
test_images = test_data.flow_from_directory(test_dir,
                                            batch_size=20,
                                            class_mode='binary',
                                            target_size = (150,150))



import tensorflow as tf

model = tf.keras.Sequential ([
                              tf.keras.layers.Conv2D (16, (3,3), activation='relu', input_shape =(150,150,3)),
                              tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(2,2),
                              
                              tf.keras.layers.Conv2D (32, (3,3), activation='relu'),
                              tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(2,2),
                              
                              tf.keras.layers.Conv2D (64, (3,3), activation='relu'),
                              tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(2,2),
                              tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
                              tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'),
                              tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation= 'sigmoid')

])

model.summary()

from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import RMSprop
model.compile(optimizer= RMSprop (lr=0.001), 
              loss = 'binary_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import Callback



class myCallback(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
  def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
    if(logs.get('accuracy')>0.94):
      print("\nReached 94% val_accuracy")
      self.model.stop_training = True
callbacks = myCallback()

history = model.fit(train_images,
          validation_data=test_images,
          steps_per_epoch= 76, 
          epochs=15,
          validation_steps= 19,
          callbacks= [callbacks])




import numpy as np

# uploading images to predict 
from google.colab import files
from keras.preprocessing import image

uploaded=files.upload()

for fn in uploaded.keys():
 
  # predicting images
  path='/content/' + fn
  img=image.load_img(path, target_size=(150, 150))
  
  x=image.img_to_array(img)
  x= x/255.0

  x=np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
  images = np.vstack([x])
  
  
  classes = model.predict(images, batch_size=1)
  
  print(classes)
  
  if classes[0]>0:
    print(fn + " fire")
    
  else:
    print(fn + " no fire")
```

The model is getting well as below :

```
Epoch 14/15
76/76 [==============================] - 3s 40ms/step - loss: 0.0524 - accuracy: 0.9812 - val_loss: 0.2918 - val_accuracy: 0.9474

Reached 94% val_accuracy
```

Although it might look it's overfitting or so, when I upload images to predict them the model almost always predict 1 (fire), even if I ask it to predict training images!

I tried adding a dropout layer before the last layer but not much better.
I feel like there's something wrong with the preprocessing of the images?

Comment: You should not use a `sigmoid` activation at the output layer when the preceding layers have `ReLU` activation. `Sigmoid` would output values close to 1 if the inputs are large positive numbers. On the other hand, `ReLU` always outputs positive numbers ( except some other variants ). So, the `sigmoid`s input will always come from the output of a `ReLU` function multiplied by the weights. This will lead to unstable training as the `sigmoid` will always output extreme values like 0 and 1.

Comment: I suggest you convert the binary classification problem to a multi-class classification problem.Transform the binary labels to one-hot labels and add a `softmax` function at the last `Dense` layer

Comment: Thank you a lot @ShubhamPanchal that worked. Although I did binary classification using similar CNN structure to the above on cats and dogs dataset and worked well. Multi class worked well enough here.